# Getting a sub string from a line

Tags: python, python-2.7

Usually i writes in C#

How can I cut a string?
I have this line:

```
Line 58: Oct  6 16:58:03 INTEG_245 sia_server[6830]: DbsinkConsumer.cc:262: (D) <video> 07920E: Got msg_idx=28 for evt_id=436752
```

And I need to cut the 28?

This the code i used:

```
  if (str(line).find("msg_idx=") > 0):  
    msg_id = line[line.index("Got"):line.index("For")]
```

Got an error of :

```
sg_id = line[line.index("Got"):line.index("For")]
ValueError: substring not found
```

Will be happy for an example

Comment: Have you tried string slicing?

Comment: Try `line.index("for")` (lowercase `f`)

Comment: what is string slicing?

Comment: but can I get the last index? I don't need the got..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> s= 'Line 58: Oct  6 16:58:03 INTEG_245 sia_server[6830]: DbsinkConsumer.cc:262: (D) <video> 07920E: Got msg_idx=28 for evt_id=436752'
>>> print int(re.search(r'msg_idx=(\d+)', s).group(1))
28
```

...in which `re.search()` searches for the expression `'msg_idx='`, which is preceded by `r` indicating it is a RE with escape sequences, and followed by the capture group `(  )`, which can be referenced later. the `\d+` inside means at least one numeric character. Then `group(1)` refers to the specified capture group at position 1.

Comment: Hi I tried this and I got error: self.msg_id2 =re.search(r'(?<=msg_idx=)\d+',s).group(0) TypeError: expected string or buffer –  Barak Rosenfeld 51 secs ago    edit

Comment: @BarakRosenfeld: I guess your `s` variable wasn't a string.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good way to use `line.index(example_word)` as maybe you have alot of the `example_word` in your txext and index just return the index of first match . you can use `re.sub` and positive [`look-behind`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as a more efficient way :

```
>>> s="Line 58: Oct  6 16:58:03 INTEG_245 sia_server[6830]: DbsinkConsumer.cc:262: (D) <video> 07920E: Got msg_idx=28 for evt_id=436752"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=msg_idx=)\d+','',s)
'Line 58: Oct  6 16:58:03 INTEG_245 sia_server[6830]: DbsinkConsumer.cc:262: (D) <video> 07920E: Got msg_idx= for evt_id=436752'
```

and if you want to get `28` you can use `re.search` :

```
>>> s="Line 58: Oct  6 16:58:03 INTEG_245 sia_server[6830]: DbsinkConsumer.cc:262: (D) <video> 07920E: Got msg_idx=28 for evt_id=436752"
>>> re.search(r'(?<=msg_idx=)\d+',s).group(0)
'28'
#or just use grouping :
>>> re.search(r'msg_idx=(\d+)',s).group(1)
'28'
```

Comment: Hi I tried this and I got error:  self.msg_id2 =re.search(r'(?<=msg_idx=)\d+',s).group(0)  
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @BarakRosenfeld the `s` is your string !